# formal parameters and actual parameters in c

Tags: c

**I just started learning functions and passing the parameters. so i am kind of new to this.** Here, in the following programming, i am changing the values of `a[]` which is a formal parameter. even though, the sort function is not returning anything. how are the elements in `numberArray[]` are getting sorted even though the `sort` function just dealing with the formal parameters?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sort(int[],int);
int main(void)
{
  int n;
  printf("enter the number of elements : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int numberArray[n];
  printf("enter %d numbers :\n",n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&numberArray[i]);
  sort(numberArray,n);
  printf("sorted list of numbers are :\n");
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d\n",numberArray[i]);
  return 0;
}
void sort(int a[],int n)
{
  int i,j,temp;
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
      for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
          if(a[i]>a[j])
          {
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to compare the above program with a simple program as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void nothing(int);
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("enter the value : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    nothing(a);
    printf(" a = %d",a);
    return 0;
}
void nothing(int b)
    {
        b=b+2;
    }
```

In this program, the value of `a` is not changing. Why?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments. On the other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may change the value of the object pointed to.*

Answer (score 2):

In C array parameters to functions are a fiction. Arrays don't get passed to functions; the parameter is treated as a pointer.

So in your example `a` is really an `int*`.

Personally, I think that function parameters declared as arrays is almost always a bad idea, since it doesn't model what is really being passed to the function.  Until you understand what is really happening, it can cause confusion of the sort you ran into.  It also commonly causes problems with people who try to obtain he size of the array passed to a function using the `sizeof` operator - that doesn't work since `sizeof` will return the size of a pointer type, not the actual array type.

The one situation where I think array formal arguments might make sense is with multi-dimension arrays, where the pointer arithmetic can be helpful.

Note that C99 introduced variable length arrays (VLAs) which can change much of this.  VLAs are different animals, but because support for them came rather late (even after C99 was standardized, it took a while for may implementations to support them properly). This answer doesn't necessarily apply to passing VLAs as arguments to functions.

Comment: There's a nice thing about declaring function arguments as pointers: You can make them `Type function(T argument[static N])` and tell the compiler that the pointer you're going to pass will point to at least `N` valid elements, which can help optimization.

Comment: @EOF: that is a neat feature, but I'd bet that less than 5% of C programmers have any idea about that syntax. I'm not sure how it can help optimization - it seems to me that it could help with static or runtime bounds checking.  And at least for me, two of the three C compilers I use regularly don't support the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

C passes by value ie

```
void nothing(int b) {
    b=b+2;
}
```

is getting a `copy` of the integer. If you want to see the int change you need to pass it's address ie

```
void nothing(int *b) {
  *b = *b + 2;
}
```

You pass the address as following

```
nothing(&a);
```

In the program you reference this function...

```
void sort(int a[],int n)
```

is taking a pointer to an array of integers as it's first argument so any change to it in the function changes the actual memory it `points to`

Comment: alright, that makes sense. so in the other program, doesn't `c` copy the values of `numberArray[ ]` into `a[]` before sorting it?

Comment: @buggenerator: You are misinterpreting the `int a[]` in the function prototype: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’[...]*. The argument is really a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @EOF alright. so whenever i pass an array, whatever the changes done in the function will be reflected in my original array ?

Comment: @buggenerator: Whenever you pass an array, it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array, according to *6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.* If you change an object pointed to by this pointer it will be visible in the caller, yes.

Comment: @buggenerator: When you change the elements pointed at (e.g. `a[i] = 0;` or `*a = 0;`), then the data in calling function is changed.  If you change the pointer itself (`a++`), then the change in the called function has no effect whatsoever on the calling function.

Comment: In the called function, you can increment it as shown, or use addition, or any other similar operation (the main alternatives being subtraction — not always safe).  If you want to change the pointer in the calling function, then you have to pass a pointer to the pointer, `int **p;`, and then modify that — `*p = malloc(new_size * sizeof(**p));` etc.  And you now use `(*p)[i]` to access elements of the array.  And you can't pass (the address of) an array to the function, but you can/must pass a pointer to a pointer: `int array[] = { … }; int *p = array; function(&p);`, etc.